# Not working @PostMapping 404 path not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The first request works, but on the second it gives 404, path not found
What can it be done with?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/postsViews", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Integer generateViews(@RequestBody PostViewsDTO requestDTO) throws IOException, JRException {
    viewsService.generate(requestDTO.getFileName(), requestDTO.getProjectId());
    return HttpServletResponse.SC_OK;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/favorite", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Integer generateFavorite(@RequestBody FavoriteDTO requestDTO) throws IOException, JRException {
    favoriteService.generate(requestDTO);
    return HttpServletResponse.SC_OK;
}
```

Comment: what URL did you hit? 404 error happened when URL not found.

Comment: http://host.ru/favorite 404 path /favorite not found.
At the same time, /postsViews is also in the same controller, it works fine

Comment: (
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rep")
)
POST http://localhost:8080/rep/favorite
Response:
"timestamp": "2021-12-22T14:18:04.193+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/rep/favorite"

Comment: also add first request which give you result

Comment: you should add it in description and also give minimum code which can help to reproduce...

Comment: Update your question with full class and annotation. If they are separated into more class, add another class into question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, gitlab uploaded not the last commit to the server

Answer (score -1):

There's only two things that I can think of.

First, to make sure that you are running the code that you think you are, try shutting the app down, then "clean" the project, build and run it again.

If that doesn't work, it might be a mismatch between the data that you are posting and the definition of FavoriteDTO. Try commenting out the parameter and the line of code that uses it.